# Async upload works on server, phone but not on PC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've written a controller to upload a file as an async task and return JSON whether or not it succeeded.  It works fine on the server and on my phone but when I try to run it on my computer it times out.  I'm not so much worried about it failing because it could be due to a configuration on my machine but it's not even showing that it's failing, it just times out.

The view:

```
@model Music_website.Models.MusicViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Music", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.File)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.File)
    </div>
    <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" type="submit"></button>
}
```

The Model:

```
  public class Song
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }

      [Required]
      public string songName { get; set; }

      public byte[] File { get; set; }

      private DateTime? createdDate;
      [Required]
      [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
      public DateTime CreatedDate
      {
          get { return createdDate ?? DateTime.UtcNow; }
          set { createdDate = value; }
      }
  }
```

The Controller:

```
    // POST: /Music/Upload
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Upload(MusicViewModel model)
    {
        //var user = await manager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in model.File)
            {
                Song newsong = new Song();
                byte[] uploadFile = new byte[item.InputStream.Length];
                item.InputStream.Read(uploadFile, 0, uploadFile.Length);
                newsong.songName = item.FileName;
                //newsong.Uploader = user;
                // get a stream
                newsong.File = uploadFile;
                Musicdb.Songs.Add(newsong);
                await Musicdb.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json("Upload failed");
        }
        return Json("File uploaded successfully");
    }
```

Comment: Pause the debugger while an upload is in progress. Try to catch the hang in the act.

Comment: @usr Can I even do that?  I turn on the debugger and access the URL from my PC and it does nothing when I pause it.  I'm pretty sure the debugger only runs localhost on IIS express. plz halp!